# Xamarin Pipe Failing #azure devops Pipe # error MT5209

Tags: xamarin, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have 2 repo one is Testing and another is my master.

I have xamrin code and I m using azure devops Pipe.

```
- task: ios-bundle-version@1
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 'myapp/myapp.iOS/Info.plist'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: '$(MajorVersion)'
    versionName: '$(MajorVersion)'
    printFile: true

- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '$(solutionPath)'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    packageApp: true
    buildForSimulator: false
    runNugetRestore: false
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    signingProvisioningProfileID: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
```

both branch are identical.
One branch build and success but for my master branch  i m getting below error ##

error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/runner/.nuget/packages/xamarin.build.download/.xbcache/GAppM-6.4.1/Frameworks' [/Users/runner/work/1/s/myapp/myapp.iOS/myapp.iOS.csproj]
error MT5209 : Native linking error : framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement [/Users/runner/work/1/s/myapp/myapp.iOS/myapp.iOS.csproj]
MTOUCH : error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz [/Users/runner/work/1/s/myapp/myapp.iOS/myapp.iOS.csproj]
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [/Users/runner/work/1/s/myapp/myapp.iOS/myapp.iOS.csproj]

```
42 Warning(s)
4 Error(s)
```

Any idea...

Comment: Does release or device build work on your own machine? Seems like frameworks are missing and the linking is failing

Comment: yes in local by command i can build but with azure agent in pipeline its failing

Comment: What if you run the msbuild/dotnet command instead of using the XamariniOS task?

Comment: can you suggest command line

Comment: Something as simple as: `msbuild /path/to/project.csproj /p:Configuration=Release`

Comment: same error above one

Comment: And that command works locally?

Comment: yes working locally

Comment: issue is only with pipeline

Comment: solutionFile: i added cs project path and it works thanks every one for support